# DRY way to assign hash values to an object

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm looking for a elegant way to assign the value stored inside an Hash into a pre-existed object.
Just to be clear, if I have an object, say obj with two attributes, say name and age, I want to assign this values coming from an hash without do something like:

```
obj.name = hash[:name]
obj.age = hash[:age]
```

Thanks for your attention.
Simone

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best bet is probably to simply define a method like `update_attributes` which takes a hash and does it inside an instance method of the class.

Expanding on what others have written and what you seem to need I think your best bet would be:

```
hash.keys.each do |key|
  m = "#{key}="
  obj.send( m, hash[key] ) if obj.respond_to?( m )
end
```

This will account for:

- not having all the attributes of the class in the hash at all times, and
- any number of keys in the hash (not just :name, etc)

Comment: Could you lpease explain me why you have to wirte  m = "#{key}=" insted of  m = "#{key}" ?

Comment: Well it's tricky to explain but actually very simple. First lets say for the purposes of explaining that `key` is the string `x` and `hash[key]` is `1`... Now, in Ruby the code `obj.x = 1` is actually equivalent to `obj.x=( 1 )`. So in the next line when I'm doing `obj.send( m, ... )`, I need it to _assign_ to that property. In other words, if I hadn't put the equals sign in the method name it would have called `obj.x( 1 )` and `x` simply doesn't take a parameter (because it's a property). What I want is `obj.x=( 1 )` and that's why I need `#{key}=`

Comment: You can also do: `hash.each do |key, value|` then use `value` instead of `hash[key]`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about elegant, but you can do:

```
[:name, :age].each do |att|
  obj.send("#{att}=", hash[att])
end
```

Comment: Your method looks good, but what if I have more then name and age?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty easy-to-type pattern I use for years:

```
{
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Smith",
  ...
}.each {|k, v| send("#{k}=", v)}
```

Comment: I would use `public_send`

Comment: @kode, sounds reasonable, but over the years I've **never** run into a case when `attr=` were private.

Answer (score 2):

Using `instance_variable_set` is another option. Here is an example:

```
class Test; attr_accessor :name, :age; end

hash = {name: 'John', age: 52}

obj = Test.new
hash.each do |k,v|
  obj.instance_variable_set("@#{k}".to_sym, v) # :name is converted to :@name
end

p obj # => #<Test:0x007fd8cbb75b00 @name="John", @age=52>
```

The only trick is that instance_variable_set expects a symbol starting with `@` so `:@name` is valid but `:name` is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.methods.grep(/[^!=]=$/).each {|attr| obj.send(attr, hash[attr]) }
```

Comment: Probably want to at least add a `if hash.has_key?(attr)` in there in case you don't have every attribute of the object in the hash.

Comment: @thenduks: As far as I can decode the specification, the object has two attributes which are always in the hash. But of course, the question isn't exactly well worded. It should probably at least have a specification and a test suite to be answered properly.

Comment: Your method seems very tidy, but could you explain me what the regular expression stand for ?

Comment: @user442622: I want to get all setter methods, i.e. all methods that end with an equals sign (that's the `=$` part), but there are a couple of other methods that also end with an equals sign (namely `==`, `===` and `!=`), so I match only on those which do not have `!` or `=` as their second-to-last character (that's the `[^!=]` part).

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call the assign_attributes method on the object.

```
obj.assign_attributes(hash)
```

Comment: This is an Active Record specific API, not a Ruby standard library one.