# Iterate over model attributes and check error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, attributes, bdd

I am trying to iterate over an object and change its attributes while testing with rspec. The idea is to test that the strings are not too long (max 255 chars). Since there are so many, I want to avoid repetitive code and iterate over the object's attributes.

I have come up with the following thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669801/dry-way-to-assign-hash-values-to-an-object):

```
[ :city, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :office_name, :street ].each do |attr|
    c.send("#{attr}=", long_string)
    c.errors[attr].should include "is too long (maximum is 255 characters)"
end
```

However, the console says

```
expected [] to include "is too long (maximum is 255 characters)"
```

The long_string is in fact 1000 chars long, so that can't be the problem. In the according model I am already making sure that the maximum length of each of the above attributes is 255. I am not really sure whether I am doing something wrong while assigning or whether it is something about the test that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeeze in a `c.valid?` between your `c.send` and `c.errors` statements.

i.e. *before* accessing `c.errors`

The `errors` Array is empty until your model is validated. Either through checking `valid?` or when attempting to save it.

You can find more about the `errors` Array and validations in the [Validations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#valid-and-invalid)

Comment: Thanks very much! I decided to use c.should_not be_valid to stick to rspec lingo.

Comment: in this case you should make sure that the subject is valid before setting the `long_string`, otherwise you can't be sure if it is not some other validation that makes the subject invalid

Comment: Isn't it enough to check that the errors array has the right error like I am doing? Then it should be rightfully invalid.

Comment: Oh, yes that's enough. I was under the impression that you wanted to _replace_ the check of the `errors` Array with `should_not be_valid`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, if you are using `ActiveRecord` the `errors` won't be populated until validations are triggered.

```
[ :city, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :office_name, :street ].each do |attr|
    c.send("#{attr}=", long_string)
    c.valid? # Run validations by asking is the record is valid
    c.errors[attr].should include "is too long (maximum is 255 characters)"
end
```