# Ruby object mass assignment

Tags: ruby, accessor

Is there any better way to do the below code?

```
user.name = "abc"
user.email = "abc@test.com"
user.mobile = "12312312"
```

Something like this will do:

```
user.prepare do |u|
  u.name = "abc"
  u.email = "abc@test.com"
  u.mobile = "12312312"
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DRY way to assign hash values to an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669801/dry-way-to-assign-hash-values-to-an-object)

Comment: If `user` is an `ActiveRecord` then [`attributes=`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes) might be an option.

Comment: Why do you like your second example better than the first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) let's you do exactly that:

```
user.tap do |u|
  u.name = "abc"
  u.email = "abc@test.com"
  u.mobile = "12312312"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative option when your attributes come in the form of a hash:

```
attrs = {
  name: "abc",
  email: "abc@test.com",
  mobile: "12312312"
}

attrs.each { |key, value| user.send("#{key}=", value) }
```

Comment: This won't work as `user.send(key)` will call the getter - not the setter method. You need to do `user.send("#{key}=")`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

With ActiveRecord objects you can use [`.assign_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes)  or the update 
methods:

```
user.assign_attributes( name: "abc", email: "abc@test.com", mobile: "12312312")
# attributes= is a shorter alias for assign_attributes
user.attributes = { name: "abc", email: "abc@test.com", mobile: "12312312" }

# this will update the record in the database
user.update( name: "abc", email: "abc@test.com", mobile: "12312312" )

# or with a block
user.update( name: "abc", mobile: "12312312" ) do |u|
  u.email = "#{u.name}@test.com" 
end
```

`.update` accepts a block, while assign_attributes does not. If you are simply assigning a hash of literal values - such as those passed by a user in the params then there is no need to use a block.

If you have a plain old ruby object which you want to spice up with mass assignment you can do:

```
class User

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :mobile

  def initialize(params = {}, &block)
    self.mass_assign(params) if params
    yield self if block_given?
  end

  def assign_attributes(params = {}, &block)
    self.mass_assign(params) if params
    yield self if block_given?
  end

  def attributes=(params)
    assign_attributes(params)
  end

  private
    def mass_assign(attrs)
      attrs.each do |key, value|
        self.public_send("#{key}=", value)
      end
    end
end
```

This will let you do:

```
u = User.new(name: "abc", email: "abc@test.com", mobile: "12312312")
u.attributes = { email: "abc@example.com", name: "joe" }
u.assign_attributes(name: 'bob') do |u|
  u.email = "#{u.name}@example.com"
end

# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following as well:

```
user.instance_eval do 
    @name = "abc"
    @email = "abc@test.com"
    @mobile = "12312312"
end
```

You can access the instance variables of `user` inside the block given to `instance_eval`

---

You could use the below code if you wish to invoke the accessor methods instead of directly manipulating the instance variables.

```
user.instance_eval do
    self.name = "xyz"
    self.email = "abc@test.com"
    self.mobile = "12312312"
end
```

or

```
user.instance_eval do |o|
    o.name = "xyz"
    o.email = "abc@test.com"
    o.mobile = "12312312"
end
```

Comment: I would not recommend this though as `instance_eval` breaks the rules of encapsulation. Better to use `.tap` or `.send` as already recommended.

Comment: @max `send` too breaks the encapsulation ;-)  Ruby's encapsulation is only for well-behaved programmers.

Comment: You're right there. `public_send` does though. And one could wish that `.send` did.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'user' is a class that you control, then you can just define a method to do what you want.  For example:

```
def set_all(hash)
  @name, @email, @mobile = hash[:name], hash[:email], hash[:mobile]
end
```

And then in the rest of your code:

```
user.set_all(name: "abc", email: "abc@test.com", mobile: "12312312")
```

If 'user' is an instance of, say, an ActiveRecord model, then I'm a little shaky on the details of how you would get this to work.  But the principal still applies: DRY up code by moving the responsibility for the complexity to the receiver.