# Having a hash, set object properties in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having a hashmap, such as:

```
{:foo => 1, :bar => 2}
```

in Ruby, is there an easy way to assign those values as properties of the object, to automatically cause this to happen:

```
obj.foo = 1
obj.bar = 2
```

To be precise, some Ruby-idiomatic way of doing:

```
hashmap.each { |k,v| obj.send("#{k}=", v) }
```

obj is an object that doesn't inherit ActiveModel and it's not a Struct and I can't control it's type as it's coming from a third party library.

I'm using Rails, so if the answer comes from Rails, that's acceptable.

Comment: Well, it depends from what is `obj`... for example, if it is an ActiveRecord instance you can do `obj.attributes = hashmap`

Comment: I think for your question a Struct could be what you are looking for. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html

Comment: obj is an object of a third party class that already exists. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Pablo so `obj` can have any key? as in `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`? or there are predefined keys that would be coming from third party library? as in is there a contract with this library to provide certain keys?

Comment: @Surya the hashmap can have any keys. The object has a predefined set of keys which can vary and it's ok for the code to raise an exception if I enter a key in the hashmap that doesn't exist in the object.

Comment: What's wrong with your `hashmap.each` approach? You don't own `obj` so altering its interface through monkey patching could be problematic and `send` is the idiomatic way to call a method by name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DRY way to assign hash values to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669801/dry-way-to-assign-hash-values-to-an-object)

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is (almost) the most concise, readable, idiomatic solution already:

```
hashmap.each { |k,v| obj.send("#{k}=", v) }
```

There is only one thing left to improve:

```
hashmap.each { |k,v| obj.public_send("#{k}=", v) }
```

Use `public_send` instead of `send` to make it clear to others that you are using it only to pass a method name dynamically and not to circumvent access restrictions.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me if the accessors were already defined on the class. If not, he could always add them with `Foo.class_eval { attr_accessor :bar, :foo }` (among probably a dozen different other options as well)

Comment: @JayDorsey what’s wrong with direct call: `Foo.attr_accessor :bar, :foo`?

Comment: The OP stated (in the comments) that the object is outside the OP's control (which presumable means it shouldn't be modified, although that is of course always possible in Ruby), that the keys match up with already existing accessors, and that failing with an exception is the correct thing to do if they don't.

Comment: @mudasobwa Calling as `Foo.attr_accessor` returns a NoMethodError (private method). Does it not for you?

Comment: @JörgWMittag excellent point. I missed the follow-up questions that stated the keys were pre-defined. No need for `attr_accessor`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create an [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) from your hash, do whatever you need with the OpenStruct and its attributes, then convert it back into a hash?

```
require 'ostruct'

h = {:foo => 1, :bar => 2}
o = OpenStruct.new(h)
o.foo  # Output: => 1
o.bar  # Output: => 2

# if necessary, convert it back into a hash
h = o.to_h
```

From the [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html):

> An OpenStruct is a data structure, similar to a Hash, that allows the
>   definition of arbitrary attributes with their accompanying values.
>   This is accomplished by using Ruby’s metaprogramming to define methods
>   on the class itself.
>
> An OpenStruct utilizes Ruby’s method lookup structure to and find and
>   define the necessary methods for properties. This is accomplished
>   through the method method_missing and define_method.
>
> This should be a consideration if there is a concern about the
>   performance of the objects that are created, as there is much more
>   overhead in the setting of these properties compared to using a Hash
>   or a Struct.

Comment: From the OP: “obj is an object that doesn't inherit ActiveModel and it's not a Struct and I can't control it's type as it's coming from a third party library.”

Comment: He would not be controlling its type; he would create a new OpenStruct with the contents of the hash, doing whatever he needs to do with the OpenStruct (accessing attributes with the dot notation) and converting it back into a hash. Not very elegant, but it avoids adding extra complexity by using unnecessary metaprogramming. Anyway, you have a valid point, maybe my suggestion is not viable...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `method_missing` if you need to set data dynamically.

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(sym, *args)
    super unless instance_variables.include?("@#{sym}".to_sym)
    instance_variable_get("@#{sym}")
  end
end

obj = Foo.new

h = {:foo => 1, :bar => 2}

h.each { |k, v| obj.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }

obj.foo
# => 1
obj.bar
# => 2
```

Comment: It’s much better to `define_method` amongst `instance_variable_set` then overload `method_missing`.

Comment: `self.singleton_class.define_method`?

Comment: @mudasobwa Oh, ok. Post it like answer. I dont rly know that. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on mobile so let's give this a try:

```
    class Something
         attr_reader :foo, :bar

          def initialize(hash = {})
               foo = hash[:foo]
               bar = hash[:bar]
          end
     end

     obj = Something.new({foo: 1, bar: 2})

     obj.foo = 1
     obj.bar =2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Klass
  def initialize(h)
    h.each { |iv, val| instance_variable_set("@#{iv}", val) }
  end
end

k = Klass.new(:foo => 1, :bar => 2)
  #=> #<Klass:0x007ff1d9073118 @foo=1, @bar=2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, a minor improvement on your suggested solution would be to use `Object#try` from Active support extensions

```
hashmap.each {|k,v| obj.try "#{k}=", v }
```

As per [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object%3Atry),

> Invokes the public method whose name goes as first argument just like
>   public_send does, except that if the receiver does not respond to it
>   the call returns nil rather than raising an exception.